# My return type should be right but Intelli-J says it is wrong? ArrayList<ArrayList<Card>> needed, boolean found

Tags: java, oop, intellij-idea, arraylist, return-type

I am writing (essentially) an N choose R method that should return a list of possible combinations. Intelli-J is telling me that my ArrayList which I am adding ArrayList to says that its returning a boolean type in the first if statement instead. And in the next few statements I am doing the same thing but it doesn't show that I have any errors there. Here is my code (my recursion is probably wrong right now but I can't test my methof until this error is fixed):

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Card>> choose(ArrayList<Card> from, int howMany)
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Card>> toReturn = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Card>>();
    if (from.size() == howMany)
    {
        return toReturn.add(from);
    }
    else if (howMany == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < from.size() -1; i++)
        {
            ArrayList<Card> oneCardList = new ArrayList<Card>();
            Card card = from.get(i);
            oneCardList.add(card);
            toReturn.add(oneCardList);
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
    for (Card card : from) {
        Card first = card;
        ArrayList<Card> theRest = new ArrayList<Card>(from.subList(1, from.size() - 1));
        toReturn.add(theRest);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Card>> chooseRest = choose(theRest, howMany);
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `toReturn.add(from);` that returns a boolean, not a List.
I guess you should do something like this:

```
toReturn.add(from);
return toReturn;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it is, read the API docs on array list. You have to return the list, add returns boolean to tell you if the insertion into the list was successful or not

```
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)
```